# Using a for if loop to add together elements in list and compare to a number, a

Tags: r

So I was given this question, Write an R function that, given a vector x and a value a, finds the smallest value of n such that the sum of the first n elements of x is bigger than a, or NA if no such n exists, using a for loop.

```
nloop=function(x,a){
sum=0
  for (i in 1:length(x))
sum = sum + x[i]
if (sum>a)
  end=x[i]
end

}
```

but this always gives me the last value in the vector?

Comment: Your loop doesn't break when `sum > a` the first time so it just keeps going until the end regardless. Also, hint: `?cumsum`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nloop=function(x,a){
  sum=0
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    sum = sum + x[i]
  if (sum>a){
    ends=x[i];break}
  }
  ends
}
```